# How to Work with nested data in angular 4 with bootstrap 4 data-table?

Tags: angular, datatable, bootstrap-4

I am Using the Data Table from git project: https://github.com/afermon/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4-demo. It works fine with data-structure like key-value as given in sample. But i am struggling with nested data.What should i put in [property] value if my data is nested. I tried using dot(.) but it doesn't help.
 
   `

```
<data-table-column [property]="'Suppliers.SupplierName'"
                               [header]="'Supplier'"
                               [sortable]="true"
                               [visible]="true">
            </data-table-column>
```

` 
My data structure looks like this:

```
     "Suppliers": [
            {
                "ResponseNumber": "1234561",
                "SupplierName": "Kirloskar pumps",
                "ContactPerson": "Ram Kumar",
                "Status": "Released",
                "TotalValueQuoted": "0"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am too late to answer this but might help others

You can use ng-template

```
<data-table-column
        [property]="'Email'"
        [header]="'Mapped'"
        [width]="100">
        <ng-template #dataTableCell let-item="item">
        {{item.obj1.value}}
        </ng-template>
    </data-table-column>
```

here item is iterative element and just fetch nested value and display it.